# Conditionally Rendering Markup (JSX) vs. CSS `display: none` - Which is better practice?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Say I've got a component with identical content, but presented two totally different markup structures depending on the device (desktop viewports or mobile viewports).

In this situation when the viewport is below or above certain width or breakpoint (for this example `768px`), I want to show one over the other.

A common situation for something like this might be the Navigation, where at Desktop views you have a simple navigation bar in the header of the page, whilst at Mobile views you have a more complex navigation menu that slides in and out:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navigation.scss';

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navigation">
      <div className="mobile-navigation-container">
        <MobileNavigation />
      </div>
      <div className="desktop-navigation-container">
        <DesktopNavigation />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Solution 1:

A simple solution to achieve this is to use CSS:

```
.navigation {
  .mobile-navigation-container {
    @media (min-width: 768px){
      display: none;
    }
  }
  .desktop-navigation-container {
    @media (max-width: 767px){
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

However, the issue here is that I still have both views in the DOM, even though one is not visible.

### Solution #2:

Alternatively, I can use a resize listener and piece of state in my JSX component to conditionally render the correct component depending on the viewport width I can calculate using `window.innerWidth`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';

class Navigation extends Component {
  state = {
    viewportWidth: 0,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (isClient) {
      this.updateWindowDimensions();
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (isClient) window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
  }

  updateWindowDimensions = () => {
    this.setState({ viewportWidth: window.innerWidth });
  }

  render() {
    const { viewportWidth } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="navigation">
        {viewportWidth <= 768 && (
          <div className="mobile-navigation-container">
            <MobileNavigation />
          </div>
        )}
        {viewportWidth > 768 && (
          <div className="desktop-navigation-container">
            <DesktopNavigation />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This solves the issue of having duplicate content on the DOM. Which I'd guess is better for Search Engine Crawlers.

However, this somewhat makes my JSX more complicated, and I have the feeling that the CSS breakpoint is cleaner, smoother implementation in terms of performance, rather than using a JavaScript resize listener (though I can't find solid sources to advise one over the other).

My question is which of these two implementations is better practice and why?

Comment: From [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), but about the same question: "Generally speaking, `v-if` [conditional rendering] has higher toggle costs while `v-show` [css hiding] has higher initial render costs. So prefer `v-show` [css hiding] if you need to toggle something very often, and prefer `v-if` [conditional rendering] if the condition is unlikely to change at runtime." Since switching devices mid-view is not very likely...

Comment: @Amadan, What if you are doing SSR (e.g., with Next/Nuxt)? If you use a resize detector to determine whether you have a narrow or wide screen, wouldn't you end up server rendering the wrong thing a lot of the time since you can't predict the device width when the page is requested from the server? It seems like it would be better to use #1 for SSR and #2 once on the client. Not easy to have both solutions in one codebase, though.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach Solution #2 is very good as compared to Solution #1. Because #1 has unnecessary and unwanted elements in DOM Object which is also confusing for react. Although it is not a good practice in any other languages as well. But in #2 you are not rendering unwanted contents this will improve smooth running of your code and debugging and designing is also easy in this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the 2nd one even though it involves more lines of code, the overall performance outcome is much better because you don’t have extra pieces of DOM elements laying unnecessarily here and there in the page. 
What’s more important is the flexibility provided by solution 2, what if you have to change the underlying markup on different screens in the future? (ex. hide some columns in smaller screens)